# SQL Server Data redundancy

Tags: sql, sql-server, join, redundancy

I'm trying to find out the pitstop strategy followed by teams in F1 and which strategy on average yields the better winning results. However every time I try to execute the query I just get redundant data.

Dataset Example:

DriverTable

| DriverId | DriverRef | DriverNumber |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Lewis | 22 |
| 2 | Alonso | 14 |
| 3 | Max | 1 |

RaceResult

| ResultID | RaceID | DriverID | Number | Position | Laps |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 12 | 1 | 22 | 1 | 53 |
| 1 | 12 | 2 | 14 | 6 | 53 |
| 1 | 12 | 3 | 1 | 2 | 53 |
| 2 | 13 | 1 | 22 | 2 | 57 |
| 2 | 13 | 2 | 14 | 6 | 57 |
| 2 | 13 | 3 | 1 | 1 | 57 |

Races

| RaceID | year | CircuitID | Name |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 12 | 2009 | 1 | Monza |
| 13 | 2013 | 2 | Bahrain Sakhir |

PitStops

| RaceID | DriverID | Stop | Lap |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 12 | 1 | 1 | 17 |
| 12 | 1 | 2 | 34 |
| 12 | 2 | 1 | 14 |
| 12 | 2 | 2 | 42 |
| 12 | 3 | 1 | 20 |
| 12 | 3 | 2 | 37 |
| 13 | 1 | 1 | 14 |
| 13 | 1 | 2 | 32 |
| 13 | 2 | 1 | 12 |
| 13 | 2 | 2 | 34 |
| 13 | 3 | 1 | 20 |
| 13 | 3 | 2 | 42 |

My desired result table would look something similar to this.

StrategyChoices

| DriverRef | RaceID | CircuitID | Name | Stop | Lap |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Lewis | 12 | 1 | Monza | 1 | 17 |
| Lewis | 12 | 1 | Monza | 2 | 34 |
| Max | 13 | 2 | Bahrain Sakhir | 1 | 20 |
| Max | 13 | 2 | Bahrain Sakhir | 2 | 42 |

The goal here find out what pit strategy did the winning driver use on a certain track.

```
SELECT ra.year, ra.name, d.properdriverref, (SELECT DISTINCT re.number FROM results WHERE re.position = 1), p.stop, p.lap, re.position
FROM pit_stops p
JOIN results re ON re.raceId = p.raceId
JOIN races ra ON p.raceId = ra.raceId
JOIN DriversXL d ON p.driverId = d.driverId    
WHERE ra.year >= 2018 AND re.position = 1
```

Was the code that I used and the data set returned a

| DriverRef | RaceID | CircuitID | Name | Stop | Lap |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Lewis | 12 | 1 | Monza | 1 | 17 |
| Lewis | 12 | 1 | Monza | 2 | 34 |
| Max | 12 | 1 | Monza | 1 | 17 |
| Max | 12 | 1 | Monza | 2 | 34 |
| Alonso | 12 | 1 | Monza | 1 | 17 |
| Alonso | 12 | 1 | Monza | 2 | 34 |
| Max | 13 | 2 | Bahrain Sakhir | 1 | 20 |
| Max | 13 | 2 | Bahrain Sakhir | 2 | 42 |
| Lewis | 13 | 2 | Bahrain Sakhir | 1 | 20 |
| Lewis | 13 | 2 | Bahrain Sakhir | 2 | 42 |
| Alonso | 13 | 2 | Bahrain Sakhir | 1 | 20 |
| Alonso | 13 | 2 | Bahrain Sakhir | 2 | 42 |

Comment: Nothing appears incorrect with your query based on the info provided. Simple check would be to use ```SELECT *``` and then comment out each join one by one, until your number of rows are correct. If I had to guess, there's a composite key and you missed the second column or perhaps may just have a wrong table , like maybe you should be using ```driver``` and not ```DriverXL```

Comment: I have attempted to re-create a whole new dataset just for the winners but the problem is that its showing me a lot of redundant data. I tried using the distinct clause but to no avail so I'm kinda stuck now

Comment: Please highlight which are the redundant data

Comment: So I am unaware on how to format a comment like a post, but for the data, it shows all the pitstops that the drivers took on a certain track and not the winning driver which yields unnecessary data

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Two SQL LEFT JOINS produce incorrect result](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12464037/two-sql-left-joins-produce-incorrect-result)

Comment: Is the that the actual query ? the result columns doesn't really matches with the sample result that you have shown

Comment: Double check the `join` condition between the table. Like `pit_stops` and `results`. You only join on `raceId`. Why `driverId` is not in the join condition

Comment: the sub-query is rather weird `(SELECT DISTINCT re.number FROM results WHERE re.position = 1)` What are you trying to do here ? Why don't you just return `re.number` directly since you already have `result` table in the `FROM` tables

Comment: Thank you everyone for participating the answer seemed to have answered my problem. To answer the questions above: I tried using distinct to show the driver number where their finishing position was first. I believe it was a join issue, if anyone has any type of resources for a proper join tutorial it'll be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing an extra join column between `pit_stop` and `results`.

> It's unclear the point of that subquery, so I have removed it

```sql
SELECT
  d.driverref,
  r.raceId,
  r.circuitId,
  ra.year,
  ra.name,
  p.stop,
  p.lap
FROM pit_stops p
JOIN results re ON re.raceId = p.raceId AND re.DriverID = p.DriverID
JOIN races ra ON p.raceId = ra.raceId
JOIN DriversXL d ON p.driverId = d.driverId    
WHERE re.position = 1;
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=c486219432e93f3afab515e5cbed83ed)